# line collision detector with circles

Tags: python, pygame

not long ago I am in python and I decided to make a path planning program, the truth cost me a lot since I am a beginner, but good to the point, is to generate circles of random size and position that do not collide with each other and then generate lines that do not collide with the circles, with much help and I managed to generate the circles without colliding but I can not generate the lines and much less that do not collide, I would greatly appreciate if you could help me and tell me what is wrong or missing

this is my code  main:

```
import pygame as pg
from Circulo import Circulo
from Linea import Linea
from random import *

class CreaCir:
    def __init__(self, figs):
        self.figs = figs
        
    def update(self):
        if len(self.figs) <70:
            choca = False
            r = randint(5, 104)
            x = randint(0, 600 + r)
            y = randint(0, 400 + r) 
            creOne = Circulo(x, y, r)
            for  fig in (self.figs):
                choca = creOne.colisionC(fig)
                if choca == True:
                    break
            if choca == False:
                self.figs.append(creOne)
           
    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pass

class CreaLin:
    def __init__(self, lins):
        self.lins = lins

    def update(self):
        if len(self.lins) <70:
            choca = False
            x = randint(0, 700)
            y = randint(0, 500)
            a = randint(0, 700) 
            b = randint(0, 500)
            linOne = Linea(x, y, a, b)
            for  lin in (self.lins):
                choca = linOne.colisionL(lin)
                if choca == True:
                    break
            if choca == False:
                self.lins.append(linOne)        
    
    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pass


class Ventana:
    def __init__(self, Ven_Tam= (700, 500)):
        
        pg.init()
        self.ven_tam = Ven_Tam

        self.ven = pg.display.set_caption("Linea")
        self.ven = pg.display.set_mode(self.ven_tam)
        self.ven.fill(pg.Color('#404040'))
        self.figs = []
        self.lins = []
        self.reloj = pg.time.Clock()
        
    def check_events(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or (event.type == pg.KEYDOWN and event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE):
                quit()
        pg.display.flip()

    def run(self):
        cirCreater = CreaCir(self.figs)
        linCreater = CreaLin(self.lins)
        while True:
            self.check_events()
            cirCreater.update()
            linCreater.update()

            for fig in self.figs:
                fig.dibujar(self.ven)

            for lin in self.lins:
                lin.dibujar(self.ven)

            self.reloj.tick(60)
                 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ven = Ventana()
    ven.run()
```

class Circulo:

```
class Circulo(PosGeo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radio = r
        self.cx = x+r
        self.cy = y+r

    def __str__(self):
      return f"Circulo, (X: {self.x}, Y: {self.y}), radio: {self.radio}"

    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pg.draw.circle(ventana, "white", (self.cx, self.cy), self.radio, 1)
        pg.draw.line(ventana, "white", (self.cx+2, self.cy+2),(self.cx-2, self.cy-2))
        pg.draw.line(ventana, "white", (self.cx-2, self.cy+2),(self.cx+2, self.cy-2))

    def update(self):
        pass

    def colisionC(self, c2):
        return self.radio + c2.radio > sqrt(pow(self.cx - c2.cx, 2) + pow(self.cy - c2.cy, 2))
    
   
    def colisionL(self, l1):
        den = sqrt(l1.a*l1.a+l1.b*l1.b)
        return abs(l1.a*self.cx+l1.b*self.cy+l1.c)/den < self.radio
```

and finally my class line:

```
class Linea(PosGeo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, a, b):
        super().__init__(x, y)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def dibujar(self, ventana):
        pg.draw.line(ventana, "#7B0000", (self.x, self.y), (self.a, self.b))

    def update(self):
        pass
    
    def colisionL(self, l1):
        pass
```

Comment: Here's a lesson on lines intersecting circles: 
 https://doubleroot.in/lessons/circle/intersection-line-circle-1/

Comment: I notice that you are storing the upper left of the circle's bounding box (x,y) as well as the circle's center (cx, cy).  The upper left of the bounding box is usually not that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm that detects the intersection of a line and a circle is wrong.A correct algorithm can be found all over the web. e.g. [Circle-Line Intersection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.htm). A function that implements such an algorithm and finds the intersection points of a line and a circle could look like the following:

```py
def sign(x):
    return -1 if x < 0 else 1

def interectLineCircle(l1, l2, cpt, r):
    x1 = l1[0] - cpt[0]
    y1 = l1[1] - cpt[1]
    x2 = l2[0] - cpt[0]
    y2 = l2[1] - cpt[1]
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dr = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    D = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
    discriminant = r*r*dr*dr - D*D
    if discriminant < 0:
        return []
    if discriminant == 0:
        return [((D * dy ) /  (dr * dr) + cpt[0], (-D * dx ) /  (dr * dr) + cpt[1])]
    xa = (D * dy + sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    xb = (D * dy - sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    ya = (-D * dx + abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    yb = (-D * dx - abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    return [(xa + cpt[0], ya + cpt[1]), (xb + cpt[0], yb + cpt[1])]
```

If you just want to check if the line and the circle intersect, but you don't need the intersection points, you can simply return `discriminant > 0`:

```py
def interectLineCircle(l1, l2, cpt, r):
    x1 = l1[0] - cpt[0]
    y1 = l1[1] - cpt[1]
    x2 = l2[0] - cpt[0]
    y2 = l2[1] - cpt[1]
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dr = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    D = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
    discriminant = r*r*dr*dr - D*D
    return discriminant > 0
```

If you want to check for line segments instead of endless lines, you must also check whether the intersection points are on the line segment:

```py
def interectLineCircle(l1, l2, cpt, r):
    x1 = l1[0] - cpt[0]
    y1 = l1[1] - cpt[1]
    x2 = l2[0] - cpt[0]
    y2 = l2[1] - cpt[1]
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dr = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    D = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
    discriminant = r*r*dr*dr - D*D
    if discriminant < 0:
        return []
    if discriminant == 0:
        xa = (D * dy ) /  (dr * dr)
        ya = (-D * dx ) /  (dr * dr)
        ta = (xa-x1)*dx/dr + (ya-y1)*dy/dr
        return [(xa + cpt[0], ya + cpt[1])] if 0 < ta < dr else []
    
    xa = (D * dy + sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    ya = (-D * dx + abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    ta = (xa-x1)*dx/dr + (ya-y1)*dy/dr
    xpt = [(xa + cpt[0], ya + cpt[1])] if 0 < ta < dr else []
    
    xb = (D * dy - sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr) 
    yb = (-D * dx - abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    tb = (xb-x1)*dx/dr + (yb-y1)*dy/dr
    xpt += [(xb + cpt[0], yb + cpt[1])] if 0 < tb < dr else []
    return xpt
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))

l1 = [50, 0]
l2 = [450, 300]
r = 50

def sign(x):
    return -1 if x < 0 else 1

def interectLineCircle(l1, l2, cpt, r):
    x1 = l1[0] - cpt[0]
    y1 = l1[1] - cpt[1]
    x2 = l2[0] - cpt[0]
    y2 = l2[1] - cpt[1]
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dr = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    D = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1
    discriminant = r*r*dr*dr - D*D
    if discriminant < 0:
        return []
    if discriminant == 0:
        return [((D * dy ) /  (dr * dr) + cpt[0], (-D * dx ) /  (dr * dr) + cpt[1])]
    xa = (D * dy + sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    xb = (D * dy - sign(dy) * dx * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    ya = (-D * dx + abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    yb = (-D * dx - abs(dy) * math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (dr * dr)
    return [(xa + cpt[0], ya + cpt[1]), (xb + cpt[0], yb + cpt[1])]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(250)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    cpt = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    isect = interectLineCircle(l1, l2, cpt, r)
    
    window.fill("black")
    pygame.draw.line(window, "white", l1, l2, 3)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, "white", cpt, r, 3)
    for p in isect:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, "red", p, 5)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Ok, again thank you very much for the information, one more thing, leaving aside that the lines collide, they are not being generated and the method is the same as the circle, any why?